# Wait for api response, if timout return null?

Tags: java, rest-assured

The awaitility is from maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
    <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```java
   await().atMost(Duration.TEN_SECONDS)
        .pollInterval(Duration.ONE_HUNDRED_MILLISECONDS)
        .until(()-> My Rest Call with response);
```

I want a way for if the timeout expires, will not be thrown an exception (do not know does it throw ex after time out),
instead, return null, or return a response if it exists.
And I want to avoid that I make the call again in case the response is not empty inside the timeout interval (if possible).

I do not know, why I find it complicated.:-)

Comment: Check this part of the documentation to see if it helps: https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage#example-9---ignoring-exceptions

Comment: you can just wrap your call with try catch and handle timeouts. Awaitility is not designed to serve such needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `java.util.concurrent` for what you described, no need for awaitility:

```
private Object invokeWithTimeout() {
        ExecutorService execService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Callable<Object> runWithTimeout = this::doYourThing; // Or your Lambda
        Future<Object> result = execService.submit(runWithTimeout);
        try {
            return result.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //Set your Timeout here
        } catch (TimeoutException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            result.cancel(true);            
            return null;
        }
}
```

This will return the result from `doYourThing()` or null, if the timeout is reached or another exception occurs.

Comment: Almost suitable. One thing I can not see in your answer and that is pull interval (something like fluent wait). But will try this solution tomorrow I hope